# How to convert a scala.List to a java.util.List?

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

How to convert Scala's `scala.List` into Java's `java.util.List`?

Comment: dude...change the accepted answer...(please)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Scala List and Java List are two different beasts, because the former is immutable and the latter is mutable. So, to get from one to another, you first have to convert the Scala List into a mutable collection.

On Scala 2.7:

```
import scala.collection.jcl.Conversions.unconvertList
import scala.collection.jcl.ArrayList
unconvertList(new ArrayList ++ List(1,2,3))
```

From Scala 2.8 onwards:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
asList(ListBuffer(List(1,2,3): _*))
val x: java.util.List[Int] = ListBuffer(List(1,2,3): _*)
```

However, `asList` in that example is not necessary if the type expected is a Java `List`, as the conversion is implicit, as demonstrated by the last line.

Comment: The val x: java.util.List[Int] is still immutable. Just try in Java to x.add(something) -- it will throw error

Comment: @Vitamon It doesn't throw any error for me -- I just tested it to confirm.

Comment: Deprecated in favour of `scala.collection.JavaConverters` from 2.12 on

Comment: for 2.12.1, when immediately iterating over the Java List with a Scala for loop, I've had better luck with asScalaBuffer() in the JavaConverters package: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/collection/JavaConverters$.html

Answer (score 185):

Not sure why this hasn't been mentioned before but I think the most intuitive way is to invoke the `asJava` decorator method of [JavaConverters](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConverters%24) directly on the Scala list:

```
scala> val scalaList = List(1,2,3)
scalaList: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

scala> scalaList.asJava
res11: java.util.List[Int] = [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: It also requires you to be explicit rather than depend on some implicit magic that might be unwanted some time.

Comment: This causes problems if serialising the list for subsequent use in Java code... it results in ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.convert.Wrappers. Arrays.asList(foo : _*) works in this case.

Comment: I come to this page every time I need to use Java in Scala. Unfortunately there is no way idea suggest me proper import suggestion for ".asJava" ((

Answer (score 26):

### To sum up the previous answers

Assuming we have the following `List`:

```
scala> val scalaList = List(1,2,3)
scalaList: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

---

If you want to be **explicit** and **tell exactly** what you want to convert:

```
scala> import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

scala> scalaList.asJava
res11: java.util.List[Int] = [1, 2, 3]
```

---

If you **don't want co control conversions** and let compiler make **implicit** work for you:

```
scala> import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

scala> val javaList: java.util.List[Int] = scalaList
javaList: java.util.List[Int] = [1, 2, 3]
```

It's up to you how you want to control your code.

Answer (score 23):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, the package [`scala.jdk.CollectionConverters`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/jdk/CollectionConverters$.html) provides [`asJava`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/convert/AsJavaExtensions$SeqHasAsJava.html#asJava:java.util.List[A]) via a pimp of `Seq` and replaces packages `scala.collection.JavaConverters/JavaConversions`:

```
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

// val scalaList: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
scalaList.asJava
// java.util.List[Int] = [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 9):

Pretty old questions, though I will answer, given but most of suggestions are deprecated.

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList

val myList = List("a", "b", "c")
val myListAsJavaList = seqAsJavaList[String](myList)
```

Comment: `object JavaConversions in package collection is deprecated (since 2.12.0): use JavaConverters`

Answer (score 6):

**Update**

with scala 2.9.2:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
val x: java.util.List[Int] = ListBuffer( List( 1, 2, 3 ): _* )
```

result

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

For single invocations, doing it by hand might be the simplest solution:

```
val slist = List (1, 2, 3, 4)          
val jl = new java.util.ArrayList [Integer] (slist.size)
slist.foreach (jl.add (_))
```

I didn't measure performance.

Answer (score 0):

Just doing as proposed above produces immutable list even on Java side.
The only working solution I've found is this:

```
def toJList[T](l:List[T]):util.List[T] = {
  val a = new util.ArrayList[T]
  l.map(a.add(_))
  a
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Since Scala 2.12.0 [JavaConversions has been deprecated.](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/collection/JavaConversions$.html)

So the simplest solution for me was :

```
java.util.Arrays.asList("a","b","c")
```

Comment: This answer does not explain how to use this to convert a scala list into a java list.  Arrays.asList can also be problematic as it returns an Arrays.ArrayList which is not a resizable List which can cause some unexpected errors if you think you have a util.ArrayList.

Comment: Deprecation is true, there is `import scala.collection.JavaConverters._` for 2.12.4

Comment: `scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._`'s `asJava` is the way to go I believe