# Type error trying to overwrite java method in scala

Tags: java, scala

I have a class defined in java

```
public class A {
    List<Group> javaMethod() {
    }
}
```

and a class in Scala

```
public class S extends A {
    override javaMethod: List[Group] {

    }
}
```

However, I get an error saying `method javaMethod has incompatible type`, I'm assuming because of the List that gets returned in the method when it gets overwritten, is of type scala.immutable.List, and the one that is required for the javaMethod is java.util.List.

I don't have access to class A, so I can't change the signature of the function. How can I return a scala List where I'm overriding the method, without getting a type error?

EDIT:
This will get my list from Java to Scala, but I'm wanting to convert the Java list to the Scala list.

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
asList(ListBuffer(List(1,2,3): _*))
val x: java.util.List[Int] = ListBuffer(List(1,2,3): _*)
```

Comment: I don't think you can. The return value *must* be a (subclass of) `List<Group>`. To get an entirely different return type, you must create a different method, e.g. `javaMethod2`, and assuming your implementation actually creates a `List[Group]`, you would then still override `javaMethod`, but with return type `List<Group>`, having it simply call `javaMethod2` and convert `List[Group]` to `List<Group>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a scala.List to a java.util.List?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429944/how-to-convert-a-scala-list-to-a-java-util-list)

Comment: @shmosel I want to do the reverse way

Comment: What is stopping you from using `java.util.List[Group]`?

Comment: the whole rest of the codebase that depends on that value

Comment: @ralphie9224 You have a scala list and your interface requires you to produce a java list. There's no way to change that without redefining `A`. Hence, the only solution is to convert your list to a java list. The reverse would accomplish nothing.