# HBase put[util.List[Put]) does not work

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hbase

I have been trying to insert List of Records into HBase using HBase client library.
it works for a single Put in either Table or HTable(deprecated) but does not recognize List(Puts)
Error Says: Expected: util.List, but was List

Could not understand the meaning of this error. Tried converting to JavaList but did not succeed.

Any quick advice would be higher appreciable.
`

```
  val quoteRecords = new ListBuffer[Put]()
  val listQuotes = lines.foreachRDD(rdd => {
      rdd.foreach(record => addPutToList(buildPut(record)))
   })

  table.put(quoteRecords.toList)
  quoteRecords.foreach(table.put)
  println(listQuotes)
```

`

Comment: `util.List` means `java.util.List`, which is not a Scala `List`. Where did you try to convert? Did you import the implicit conversions?

Answer (score 0):

`listQuotes.toList` returns a type of a `scala.List`. You have to convert that into a `java.util.List` type. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429944/how-to-convert-a-scala-list-to-a-java-util-list) sof thread will give you some insight.